# WPF ListView data bindings no longer work when styling xaml is added

Tags: c#, wpf, listview, data-binding, styling

I’m using a WPF ListView which binds to item properties from an observable collection. This works as expected the ListView displays my item data correctly.
My problem is that as soon as i add some styling to the xaml , the binding no longer works and the list appears to display my item data class name 'EventsTableUIParameters' instead of the data. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Here are the details:

In my code behind I have a custom collection derived from IList and IList which takes the following data items:

```
public class EventsTableUIParameters
{
    public String Summary { get; set; }
    public String TimeRaised { get; set; }
    public EventsTableUIParameters(String sDateTime, String sSummary)
    {
        Summary = sSummary;
        TimeRaised = sDateTime;
    }
}
```

The item source is set in the code behind as follows:

m_EventsListView.ItemsSource = m_myList;

The following xaml works fine:

```
<UserControl x:Class="UI.Controls.EventsTable.EventsTableControl"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:UI.Controls.EventsTable"
             xmlns:ui="clr-namespace:UI;assembly=Sonardyne.UI.MVP_HelperClasses"
             mc:Ignorable="d" d:DesignWidth="1200" d:DesignHeight="250" >  

        <ListView Name="m_EventsListView"  SelectionMode ="Single"  FontSize="16"  FontFamily="Consolas" HorizontalAlignment="Left" IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="False">
            <ListView.View>
                <GridView AllowsColumnReorder="False" > 
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Date/Time" Width="180">
                        <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type ui:EventsTableUIParameters}">
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding TimeRaised}"/>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                    </GridViewColumn>
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Summary" Width="2000">
                        <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type ui:EventsTableUIParameters}">
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Summary}"/>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                    </GridViewColumn>
                </GridView>
            </ListView.View>
        </ListView>
</UserControl>
```

As soon as I include the following style block, the data bindings no longer work:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
        <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="{Binding HorizontalContentAlignment, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ItemsControl}}}"/>
        <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="{Binding VerticalContentAlignment, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ItemsControl}}}"/>
        <Setter Property="Padding" Value="2,0,0,0"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">
                    <Border x:Name="Bd" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}" SnapsToDevicePixels="true">
                        <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"/>
                    </Border>
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="true">
                            <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="Bd" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}}"/>
                            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.HighlightTextBrushKey}}"/>
                        </Trigger>
                        <MultiTrigger>
                            <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                                <Condition Property="IsSelected" Value="true"/>
                                <Condition Property="Selector.IsSelectionActive" Value="false"/>
                            </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                            <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="Bd" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.InactiveSelectionHighlightBrushKey}}"/>
                            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.InactiveSelectionHighlightTextBrushKey}}"/>
                        </MultiTrigger>
                        <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
                            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.GrayTextBrushKey}}"/>
                        </Trigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

Comment: >the binding no longer works and the list appears to display my item data class name   << these are not the same thing. If you are seeing an item, then your binding is working just fine. Your template is broken, but not your binding.

Comment: I agree with Lynn.. Maybe you are missing the follow set in your ContentPresenter: ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}"

Comment: I tried  your suggestion, but it made no difference. I don't understand why you say that the binding is working, because I explicitly bind each of the 2 column's data template to the 2 properties in the class shown. But the ListView only shows one item in each row, namely: "EventsTableUIParameters"    - which implies it is calling ToString() on the class object itself to get a single item per row. Not sure how to proceed on this.